# How can I do:Press "Enter" automatically everytime input value changes.(JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

**I want website to press "Enter" automatically by itself,after the input value is changed.**

**Language:Javascript**

*Can anybody help with this kind of problem?!*

*Thanks in Advance!*

**So I have a searchbar which does filtration,and also I have buttons with categories(when I press the button it fills the input value to the button category name),problem:so after that i need to focus on input value and press "Enter key automatically" to filter the data.**

```js
<input
            autocomplete="off"
            type="text"
            id="myInput"
            class="searchbox-input"
            placeholder="&#128269; დასერჩე..."
            title="Type in a name"
          />
        
        <div class="available-prods-wrapper">
          <div id="available-prods" class = "available-prods">
            
              
          </div>
        </div>

        


        <script>

          
          const prodNames = [
              {id : 1, name : "ACDC"},
              {id : 2,name:  "The Beatles" },
              {id : 3,name: "Barry White"}
            ]
          

            // writes clicked button p in input
            function test(id){
            let txt = p = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
            document.getElementById("myInput").value = txt.textContent;
          }
          
            




            const prodContainer = document.getElementById('available-prods');
          
          prodNames.forEach((result, idx) => {
            // Create card element
            const prodCard = document.createElement('div');
            prodCard.classList = 'item-body';
          
            // Construct card content
            const content = `
            <div class="item" id='button-${result.id}'onclick="test(this.id);getFocus()"><p>${result.name}</p></div>
            `;
          
            // Append newyly created card element to the container
            prodContainer.innerHTML += content;  
          })
```

Comment: Can you put the code you tried to do, so we can help you ?

Comment: Ok,My fault,I have updated Mr/Mrs,check it )

Comment: I partially understood your question..  **What you want is to search after the input field is filled in button click.For that write the input filed search in the form of function and call it inside `test()` function.**
if this comment is helpful let me know or try to edit question more understandable way(Make the code Executable in code)

Comment: @Amalnandan thanks I corrected the function the way u said,it worked.

Comment: U can also answer your Question. @Rafaell444.. If u find my above comment helpful give it a up-vote so that others can see..

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you :)

```js
const prodNames = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "ACDC"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "The Beatles"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Barry White"
  }
]


// writes clicked button p in input
function test(id) {
  let txt = p = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = txt.textContent;
}


const selectElement = document.querySelector('.searchbox-input');

selectElement.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  e.keyCode = 13;
  e.click;

  //check if enter is clicked auto after input value change
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    alert('enter press');
  }
  //end check

});


const prodContainer = document.getElementById('available-prods');

prodNames.forEach((result, idx) => {
  // Create card element
  const prodCard = document.createElement('div');
  prodCard.classList = 'item-body';

  // Construct card content
  const content = `
            <div class="item" id='button-${result.id}'onclick="test(this.id);getFocus()"><p>${result.name}</p></div>
            `;

  // Append newyly created card element to the container
  prodContainer.innerHTML += content;
})
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="myInput" class="searchbox-input" placeholder="&#128269; დასერჩე..." title="Type in a name" />
<div class="available-prods-wrapper">
  <div id="available-prods" class="available-prods">
  </div>
</div>
```